# PWM timers, channels and pins

Tags: pwm, timers, avr

I've got this code from the [MultiWii](http://www.multiwii.com/) project, which is relevant to the hardware, [ATmega32u4](http://www.atmel.com/devices/ATMEGA32U4.aspx), I have. It is part of a function called `initOutput()`.

In the comment it says "connect pin 6", which is the bit of that which specifies pin 6 as I would like to change it to another pin, specifically A0.

```
// Enhanced PWM mode
TCCR4E |= (1<<ENHC4);

// Prescaler to 16
TCCR4B &= ~(1<<CS41);
TCCR4B |= (1<<CS42) | (1<<CS40);

// Phase and frequency correct mode and top to 1023, but
// with enhanced PWM mode we have 2047.
TCCR4D |= (1<<WGM40);
TC4H = 0x3;
OCR4C = 0xFF;

// Connect pin 6 to timer 4 channel D
TCCR4C |= (1<<COM4D1) | (1<<PWM4D);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `(1<<COM4D1)` that enables pin 6, or more specifically **OC4D** for timer output. You cannot use A0 instead, since there is no output compare capability on that pin; only pins 13, 5, 10, 9, 6, and 12 can be connected to timer 4. See the datasheet for details.

Comment: thanks for your answer, maybe you can help with my latest question: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/13557/32u4-timer-4-help